# A question about Carnie's subcategories and features

Tags: syntax, parts-of-speech, auxiliary-verbs, modal-verbs

From Carnie's "Syntax: A Generative Introduction":

[image]

This notation is not explicitly explained. What does it mean? (I'll write my conjecture below)

Recall that T is defined as follows:

[image]

So I guess the first row in 17) means  that the subcategory of T consisting of auxiliaries includes only non-modal and non-nonfinite verbs. The second row should mean that the subcategory of T consisting of modals includes only modal and non-nonfinite verbs. Is this a correct interpretation? It sort of makes sense to me.

But the third row is a little bit confusing. Is "to" a modal (since there is +modal mark)? Why isn't it included in "Modals" in 16) then?

Comment: Because modals (a group of verbs) and the [modal] feature are different things. Modals are [+modal] **and** [-nonfinite]. The [modal] feature can also be expressed by other means, it’s not solely expressed by modal verbs.